# Is it possible to recover original normal distributions from observations of sums of normally distributed variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, inverse-problem

I have been trying to solve the following problem for several weeks. I would greatly appreciate it if you help me solve the following problem.

**Problem description**

> Assume that there are seven iid normal distributions with zero means and different standard deviations. They are
> $$X_A \sim N(0,\sigma_A)$$
> $$X_B \sim N(0,\sigma_B)$$
> $$X_C \sim N(0,\sigma_C)$$
> $$X_{D} \sim N(0,\sigma_{D})$$
> $$X_{E} \sim N(0,\sigma_{E})$$
> $$X_{F} \sim N(0,\sigma_{F})$$
> $$X_{G} \sim N(0,\sigma_{G})$$
> Assume that we have observations of the sums of them as
> $$Y_A = X_A + X_{D}+X_{E}+X_{G}$$
> $$Y_B = X_B + X_{D}+X_{F}+X_{G}$$
> $$Y_C = X_C + X_{E}+X_{F}+X_{G}$$
> My question is: Is is possible to recover $\sigma_A$, $\sigma_B$, $\sigma_C$, $\sigma_{D}$, $\sigma_{E}$, $\sigma_{F}$, and $\sigma_{G}$ from $Y_A$, $Y_B$ and $Y_C$?　If so, how?

**What I have tried**

I built several matrix equations based on moments and correlation coefficients, but the matrix equation's rank is always 6, which is a rank-deficient problem. I missed one more condition to make a matrix equation regular... I am stuck here.

**Update 1**

I came up with the following approach, but the result is still rank = 6.
The variances of $Y_A$, $Y_B$, and $Y_C$ are given as

$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{Var}(Y_A) &= \mathrm{Var}(X_A) + \mathrm{Var}(X_{D})+\mathrm{Var}(X_{E})+\mathrm{Var}(X_{G})\\
&= \sigma^2_{A}+\sigma^2_{D}+\sigma^2_{E}+\sigma^2_{G}\\
\mathrm{Var}(Y_B) &= \sigma^2_{B}+ \sigma^2_{{D}}+\sigma^2_{{F}}+\sigma^2_{{G}}\\
\mathrm{Var}(Y_C) &= \sigma^2_{C} + \sigma^2_{{E}}+\sigma^2_{{F}}+\sigma^2_{{G}}\\
\end{split}
$$
Similarly, using the property of variance, I derived expressions for $\mathrm{Var}(Y_A-Y_B)$, $\mathrm{Var}(Y_B-Y_C)$, $\mathrm{Var}(Y_C-Y_A)$, $\mathrm{Var}(Y_A-Y_B)$, $\mathrm{Var}(Y_A+Y_B-Y_C)$, $\mathrm{Var}(Y_A-Y_B+Y_C)$, and $\mathrm{Var}(-Y_A+Y_B+Y_C)$.

Using the above expressions, I built a matrix expression in the form of $Ax =b$ where

$$
x^T  = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2_{A}  & \sigma^2_{B} & \sigma^2_{C} & \sigma^2_{D} & \sigma^2_{E} & \sigma^2_{F}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
b^T  = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{Var}(Y_A)  & \mathrm{Var}(Y_B)  & \mathrm{Var}(Y_C)  & \cdots &\mathrm{Var}(-Y_A+Y_B+Y_C)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
A  = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  &   &   & \vdots & & & \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the rank of A is $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 6$.

**Update 1 End**

**Update 2**

I thought it might be impossible to estimate all variances from $Y_*$, so I wrote a Bayesian model using stan to estimate $\sigma_*$ from $Y_*$. If a Bayesian model does not recover the variances, it might be impossible to estimate $\sigma_*$ analytically. Due to a proprietary reason, I am not allowed to provide the stan model, but I can show the result.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pystan
import arviz
import sys

%matplotlib inline

def generate_sample_data(num, seed=100):
    
    # target variance
    trueValues = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.02,0.08,0.03,0.01]
    
    np.random.seed(seed=seed)
    
    values = np.zeros((4,num))
    
    print(values)
    
    
        
    ln_A = np.random.normal(0,trueValues[0],num)
    ln_B = np.random.normal(0,trueValues[1],num)
    ln_C = np.random.normal(0,trueValues[2],num)
    ln_AB = np.random.normal(0,trueValues[3],num)
    ln_BC = np.random.normal(0,trueValues[4],num)
    ln_AC = np.random.normal(0,trueValues[5],num)
    ln_ABC = np.random.normal(0,trueValues[6],num)
    
    values[0,:] = ln_A+ln_AB+ln_AC+ln_ABC
    values[1,:] = ln_B+ln_AB+ln_BC+ln_ABC
    values[2,:] = ln_C+ln_AC+ln_BC+ln_ABC
    return values,trueValues

num = 100000

values, trueValues = generate_sample_data(num)

print(np.std(values[0]))
print(np.std(values[1]))
print(np.std(values[2]))

sample_code2 = """
// stan code with a trick here
"""

sm2 = pystan.StanModel(model_code=sample_code2)

sample_data = {
    'N': num,
    'Y_A': values[0],
    'Y_B': values[1],
    'Y_C': values[2]
}

fit2 = sm2.sampling(data=sample_data, iter=10000, chains=8,thin=3,
                  control=dict(adapt_delta = 0.99, max_treedepth=32))

print(fit2)
```

and the result is

```
            mean se_mean     sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5%  n_eff   Rhat
sigma_A      0.1  4.0e-5 3.7e-3   0.09    0.1    0.1    0.1   0.11   8706    1.0
sigma_B      0.3  1.6e-5 1.6e-3    0.3    0.3    0.3    0.3    0.3   9525    1.0
sigma_C      0.5  9.7e-6 9.7e-4    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5   9861    1.0
sigma_D     0.01  8.0e-5 7.9e-3 5.5e-4 6.1e-3   0.01   0.02   0.03   9599    1.0
sigma_E     0.08  6.2e-5 6.0e-3   0.07   0.08   0.08   0.08   0.09   9522    1.0
sigma_F     0.03  1.5e-4   0.01 2.3e-3   0.02   0.03   0.04   0.05   8215    1.0
sigma_G     0.01  7.7e-5 7.9e-3 7.3e-4 6.7e-3   0.01   0.02   0.03  10494    1.0
sigma_Y_A   0.11  2.1e-6 2.4e-4   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.11  13159    1.0
sigma_Y_B   0.31  5.5e-6 6.4e-4   0.31   0.31   0.31   0.31   0.31  13413    1.0
sigma_Y_C   0.51  1.0e-5 1.1e-3    0.5    0.5   0.51   0.51   0.51  10927    1.0
```

The Bayesian model can estimate $\sigma_*$ accurately if large numbers of samples are available. I now think it is possible to estimate $\sigma_*$ from $Y_*$.

**Update 2 End**

In the literature, I believe that a similar problem must have been studied, but I could not find any yet.

Thank you for your help and kindness.

Comment: You will need a *huge* number of observations to have any hope of estimating these standard deviations.  How many observations do you have?  What are the "correlation coefficients"?  You haven't specified any; implicitly, your readers will assume all the $X_{*}$ are independent.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I can generate as many samples $Y_A$, $Y_B$, and $Y_C$ as I want. Correlation coefficients are Pearson's product-moment coefficients. As I wrote, $X_*$s are i.i.d.

Comment: This is self-contradictory.  To what, exactly, do these correlation coefficients apply?  Because you posit "iid" distributions, that implies all their correlations are zero.

Comment: Yes, $\mathrm{corr}(X_A,X_B)=\mathrm{corr}(X_B,X_C)=\mathrm{corr}(X_C,X_A)=0$ and the same for the rest of combinations. However, $\mathrm{corr}(Y_A,Y_B) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks--I understand now.  But do you seriously hope to recover seven unknown variances from observations that enable you to estimate at most six parameters (the six covariances)?

Comment: I hope so, but it seems extremely difficult to achieve. I was able to recover seven variances using linear programming, but it was very conservative.

Comment: You must have incorporated some extra condition or conditions in your linear program, then, because identifying a unique set of seven sds is not algebraically possible.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I understand that variances and correlation coefficients of $Y_*$ are not sufficient conditions to determine variances of $X_*$. Do you know any statistics that can be used as the seventh condition?

Comment: The seventh condition would not be a statistic *per se:* it would have to be some sort of restrictive assumption (to act as a constraint) or criterion (to be optimized) that *you* choose based on the intended application.  So far, you don't seem to have posted any information of that sort, so I am at a loss to make any specific suggestion.